# Always on Top for Conversations in Skype for Business 2016

Tags: windows-10, skype-for-business

I have lost the ability to keep a Skype conversation window on top of other windows after upgrading to Windows 10 with Skype for Business 2016. Previously if you right clicked the top of a conversation window you could select "Always on top" and the conversation would be planted above everything else. This is especially useful on those late night calls when working from a single monitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this but it requires starting a second conversation.

[Single Conversation pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LvgY.jpg)

Once you start a second conversation you get a “Pop this conversation out” button on the top.

[Pop Button pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcWK4.jpg)

Clicking on that will open the conversation into a separate window and grant you you the normal right click options.

Crisis averted.

[Right Click Options pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC3b4.jpg)

Comment: This is a very useful feature. Thanks for sharing.